# draw a border equally for all ul in css

Tags: css, border

Can anyone guide me how to draw the border equally for all the ul list displayed.
Here if u see the the border between the second and third ul list is not equal to the border between the first and second ul list.There is any way to draw a border equally based on the ul     first list.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `height` of your `UL`s to be the same in your CSS declaration.

Answer (score 0):

As above just make sure you set

```
display:block
```

on your ULs and give them a fixed height, otherwise you could wrap your ULs in a DIV and apply styling to that.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your list can change, you can set the height of your  element in javascript. For example, using jquery you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uls = $("ul")
    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0, l = urls.length ; i < l ; i++) { 
        var height = $(uls[i]).height(); 
        if (height > max) { 
            max = height; 
        } 
    }
    uls.height(max);
});
```